# Does it help for clique if the vertices are partitioned into 3 cliques?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms

A graph is $(p,q)$-colorable if its vertices can be partitioned
into $p$ cliques and $q$ independent sets.

For $(2,0)$-colorable graphs clique is polynomial.

I am interested how easier (if any) is clique in $(3,0)$-colorable,
when the partitions are given.

Given graph $G$ and 3 partitions of its vertices
$A,B,C : A \cup B \cup C=V(G)$ such
that $A,B,C$ induce cliques in G.

> Q1 Is clique faster in this case?
>
> Q2 If it is faster what is the complexity?
>
> Q3 How good can we approximate clique in this case?

We have a clique $\frac{V(G)}{3}$ for free.

Answer (score 11):

Computing a maximum clique in a graph whose vertex set can be partitioned into 3 cliques, is equivalent to computing a maximum independent set in the complement graph, which can be partitioned into 3 independent sets and is therefore 3-colorable. The latter problem is still NP-complete, which can be seen as follows: Start from an arbitrary instance $(G,k)$ of independent set and subdivide each edge twice, i.e., replace each edge ${u,v}$ by a path ${u,e_1, e_2, v}$ on two new vertices. It is not difficult to prove that the resulting graph $G'$ has an independent set of size $k + |E(G)|$ if and only if $G$ has a size-$k$ independent set: for every independent set in $G$, you can add exactly one of the two subdivider vertices on every edge without violating independence.

Hence the Clique problem is still NP-complete for such inputs.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe it will be more explicit to show the sets A,B,C are {u,v},{e_1},{e_2} in the complement.